# Enabling production mode in angular 2 using enableProdMode() method not working

Tags: angular, typescript

// I have included enableProdMode() method in main.ts file of two projects as ..

```
-- main.ts--
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
enableProdMode();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

// I have tried this method in two projects, but among two projects in sample project am not getting the message that 'angular 2 app is running in development mode' but it is showing console messages.
    But even though the same enableProdMode() method is included in main project here it is showing the msg that "Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.". why it is showing in console don't know .
    Please tell me the steps to resolve these issues: 
    i). enableProdMode() method is running in one project but showing the console msgs? And
    ii). enableProdMode() method is not working in another project. here we are using- compilerOptions - target - es6 ?